# Неудачное обновление Убунту с 13.10 до 14.04. Что можно сделать?

Tags: ubuntu

Вчера, после принудительного обновления Убунту с версии 13.10 на версию 14.04, произошла видимо ошибка и перестала запускаться графическая оболочка. На этом же ноутбуке установле Виндовс 7, как вторая ОС. В mc можно войти в Убунту. Как мне спасти файлы которые лежат в папке /var/www/ и желательно файлы БД MySQL тоже скопировать. Очень не хочеться их терять. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> и перестала запускаться графическая оболочка.

Если консоль работает, то можно поробовать вручную запустить ее через вызов соответствующего скрипта в `/etc/init.d/`. Если она сама не запустится (что более чем вероятно), то, скорее всего, она оставит приличное количество ошибок, по которым можно оттрейсить причину.

Если же все равно ничего не взлетело, то есть два пути:

1. Простой. Берется лайв-сиди/флешка, запускается система без установки, все диски монитруются, файлы копируются на виндовый партишен. Сработает даже если контроль над ОС потерян целиком и полностью.
2. Консольный, труевый. С помощью команды mount в любую точку подключается виндовый партишен (или флешка, на которую нужно скинуть файлы), затем делается `cp -R /var/www /media/user/flashdrive/backup` (возможно, потребуется sudo, если что-то не то с правами; второй путь должен вести на флешку или в то место, куда скидываются файлы).
   Возможно, придется ставить ntfs-3g (но если все скидывается на fat-флешку, то проблем не будет никаких).

MySQL в любом случае лучше всего выкачивать через `mysqldump`. С помощью дампа получаются .sql-файлы, которые так же отправляются на флешку/виндовый партишен. Если зачем-то нужны сами файлы таблиц и бд, то их надо искать в `/var/lib`.

Последнее, о чем не просили, но не сказать я не могу:

> Как мне спасти файлы которые лежат в папке /var/www/

От такого помогает любая CVS (желательно, конечно, гит). У меня это стало первой причиной, из-за которой я озаботился системой версионирования и поставил svn.

> и желательно файлы БД MySQL тоже скопировать.

Здесь спасут миграции (в некоторых фреймворках это делится на миграции и фикстуры). Их довольно муторно вести (и постоянно хочется поправить уже созданные, чего делать вообще нельзя), но это окупается с лихвой при любом переносе проекта.